# How do I override python's "not in" operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I realize that `__contains__` is the the "in" operator. I also realize that, by default "not in" is the negation of `__contains__`. However, a lot of the python documentation lists "not in" as if it is a separate operator from "in." Is `__contains__` like `__eq__`
and `__ne__` where there are two operators, one *usually* the negation of the other? if so, what is the correct double-underscore `__<name>__` to use?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.numbers = [1,2,3,4,54]

def __contains__(self, key):
    return key in self.numbers
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no separate "notcontains" hook. `in` and `not in` cannot be overridden separately.

Separate `__eq__` and `__ne__` hooks exist because `==` and `!=` might not return booleans. For example, you can't implement `!=` for NumPy arrays as `not (x == y)`. `not in` doesn't have that issue, because both `in` and `not in` must return booleans.

If you look at the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), you'll see that it only documents a single `__contains__` hook for both `in` and `not in`. You can also take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Python/ceval.c#L5100), where both `in` and `not in` call the same `PySequence_Contains` C API function and then `not in` applies `!` to the result:

```c
    case PyCmp_IN:
        res = PySequence_Contains(w, v);
        if (res < 0)
            return NULL;
        break;
    case PyCmp_NOT_IN:
        res = PySequence_Contains(w, v);
        if (res < 0)
            return NULL;
        res = !res;
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to the implementation, this cannot be more explicit!